# How can I create an application launcher for a file in Gnome 3.6?

Tags: gnome

I downloaded some games from Humble Indie Bundle and now I can open them only from Nautilus and not from the applications menu, which is impractical, because usually if I want to play a game I go to "Games" under the applications menu and decide what to play, or I search the applications menu for it (from activities). I don't want to have to search two different places.

Answer (score 1):

### Create Launcher

First install gnome-panel using the following command in terminal (ctrl+alt+t)-

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

You can either create it for your own or for all users.

To create a custom launcher for yourself(current user), type in terminal-

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications/ --create-new
```

or for system wide users, type :

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
```

A window to create launcher will open up.
Fill in the -

- **Name** of the application (in your case the specific game).
- **command** field, either add the executable command or browse and navigate to /usr/bin/ (where the applications are installed) and
  select your application or game.
- **Comment** field for description (optional).

Click OK. You are good to go. The launcher is created. It will be available in the activities overview.

### Categorising

Say you created a launcher with name, indy-game. A file indy-game.desktop will be created in /usr/share/applications or /home/$USER/.local/share/applications

To make it available in the games section or any other category,

*open a terminal and type-

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

then,

```
sudo gedit indy-game.desktop
```

(replace indy-game with your launcher name)

*In the editor window that opens up, in the categories field add **Game** at the end and put a semicolon. It should look something like,

> Categories=GNOME;GTK;Game;

Done. You will have the launcher for the game available in the games category now. Create separate launcher for every game or application you want.

Hope this helps. :)